# OpenGL Correct Multiplication Order for Panning, Zooming and Rotating a 2D Camera

Tags: opengl, matrix, camera, opengl-es-2.0, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to make a Camera's View Matrix and make it zoomable, pannable and rotatable. The Matrix that I'd expect to work is.

```
Matrix.translateM(matrixView, 0, -camposition.X, -camposition.Y, 0);
Matrix.scaleM(matrixView, 0, zoom, zoom, 1.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(matrixView, 0, camrotation, 0, 0, 1.0f);
Matrix.translateM(matrixView, 0, screenwidth / 2, screenheight / 2, 0);
```

However it doesn't work this way. I would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Here's how I did the model matrix which works:

```
Matrix.translateM(matrixModel, 0, position.X, position.Y, 0.0f);
Matrix.scaleM(matrixModel, 0, scale.X, scale.Y, 1.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(matrixModel, 0, rotation, 0, 0, 1.0f);
Matrix.translateM(matrixModel, 0, -origin.X, -origin.Y, 0.0f);
```

And here's the projection matrix aswell:

```
Matrix.orthoM(matrixProj, 0, 0f, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, -1, 1);
```

I multiply them together in the vertex shader like so:

```
matrixProj * matrixView * matrixModel * vPosition;
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be translating by `-origin.XY` in your model matrix and then a few transforms later (or rather lines earlier if you read them from top-to-bottom) translate by `position.XY`? I would expect to see a translation here that puts the object back at **<0,0>** (which would mean translating by **+** `origin.xy`) before translating to `position.xy` for proper operation. Alternatively you could combine this all into a single translation: `position.xy + origin.xy`.

Comment: it's the camera's position in a different function EDITED to Denote

Comment: That still does not quite solve your problem. I assume you are translating your object to `-origin.X,-origin.Y` in order to rotate it around a certain point. But you are neglecting to move the object back to **<0,0>** before translating it to its final position. So the object is actually placed at: `position.X - origin.X, position.Y - origin.Y` right now (assuming a scale of **1.0** in all 3 coordinates).

Comment: because I want the position to point towards the center of the object. Much like in XNA C#

Comment: I honestly do not understand what that means. A position cannot point anywhere, it has no direction.

Comment: The object's center (origin) will be at the position specified. I meant it this way. Also where the camera's centered there's the position that's where it's zoomed to and rotated around.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the correct order I'll leave it for future developers facing the same problem.

```
Matrix.translateM(matrixView, 0, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2, 0);
Matrix.scaleM(matrixView, 0, camZoom, camZoom, 1.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(matrixView, 0, camRotation, 0, 0, 1.0f);
Matrix.translateM(matrixView, 0, -camPosition.X, -camPosition.Y, 0);
```

Keep in mind this is for the View Matrix. For the Model Matrix the above code works just fine.